# Need to find strings that contain the same word twice

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, arcgis-10.3, attribute-table, python-parser

I have attribute data with owner names. I need to **select** data that contains the last name **twice**.

For example, I may have an owner name that reads "**BENNETT** MCCARL & ARNETTE **BENNETT**".

I would like to select any rows in the attribute table that have a reoccurring last name such as the example above. Does anyone know how I can go about selecting that data?

Comment: What GIS are you using? Is Python an option?

Comment: 10.3 for Desktop - Python is an option.

Comment: This distils to a Python question that I think you will find the Python code for by researching/asking on [so].

Comment: I prefer not to use Python for this and would like to use SQL if possible or Field Calc.

Comment: Is this a list of last names or two people, one named Bennett McCarl and another Arnette Bennett? It appears that one person has a Bennett first name and another has a Bennett last name?

Comment: Actually, the data is messy and "Bennett" is actually the last name for both MCCARL and ARNETTE. Thus why I need to find rows where last names duplicate themselves (so I can clean up the data).

Comment: To do this I think you need to count the unique words in your string, and if it is less than the number of words in your string then there is at least one word duplicated.  Distinguishing words which are or may be surnames from other words will be a separate exercise.  I think you should [edit] your question here to make your precise requirements clearer, and combine that with Python research at [so].

Comment: I have added this in stack overflow forums. Thanks.

Comment: I've revised your question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35165648/need-to-find-strings-that-contain-the-same-word-twice because it was phrased in "ArcGIS-speak" rather than "Python-speak".  Hopefully, it won't get too many downvotes while awaiting my edit to be approved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794208/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-words-in-a-string-with-python

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798674/python-duplicate-words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field calculator expression based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798674/python-duplicate-words)

```
def cw(sentence):
 words = sentence.split()
 counts = {}
 nMax=0
 for word in words:
    if word not in counts:counts[word] = 0
    counts[word] += 1
    nMax=max(nMax, counts[word])
 return nMax
```

'==================================================

```
cw( !MUID!)
```

It will return maximum count of same words in the string

Answer (score 8):

You can use the Python [collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) module and an Update Cursor to accomplish this. This method adds a new field and populates it with a `1` if there are any duplicates, otherwise a `0` if there are no duplicates.

```
import arcpy, collections

shp = r'C:\temp\names.shp'

# Add a field called "check" to store binary data.

arcpy.AddField_management(shp, field_name = "check", field_type = "SHORT")

# Use an Update Cursor to query the table and write to new rows
# 1 = has duplicates
# 0 = no duplicates
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(shp, ["last_names", "check"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        names = row[0].replace("&", "").split() # Clean the string
        counts = collections.Counter(names) #create dictionary to count occurrences of words
        if any(x > 1 for x in list([count for name, count in counts.items()])):
            row[1] = 1
        else:
            row[1] = 0
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

---

[image]

Comment: Nice use of this collections module, never knew it existed. I was thinking on the same lines but using regular expressions to extract out repeating words to create a flag field. I think your approach using the counter function is much easier to understand. I will be checking out that module later!

Answer (score 6):

What about using `re` and `set` and setting a flag ( here 0 and 1) in python- `re` will extract all the names (last and first) from `BENNETT MCCARL & ARNETTE BENNETT` without `&`. For pattern matching `re` is of highest priority- you can use `re` how you want.

```
import re
def sorter(val):
    words = re.findall(r'\w+',val)
    uniques = set(words)
    if len(words)>len(uniques):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

---

And call `sorter( !N! )`

---

[image: demo]

---

**See how `regex` grabs words at <kbd>[LIVE DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xS3aO6/1)</kbd>

Note that all of these answers deal the problem supposing that your data is sanitized i.e. have proper **space between words** but what if your data is something like `BENNETTMCCARL&ARNETTEBENNETT` then all these would fail. In that case you may need to use [Suffix Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) algorithm and fortunately python has some library as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347078/python-library-for-generalized-suffix-trees).

Comment: regex to the rescue, nice!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your source data is a FeatureClass/Table in a File GeoDatabase then the following query will select the rows you require:

```
SUBSTRING(name FROM 1 FOR 7) = 'BENNETT' AND SUBSTRING(name FROM (CHAR_LENGTH(name) - 6) FOR 7) = 'BENNETT
```

`name` is the field, I just happened to call it `name`. The first part is testing the left hand side the second part is testing the right. This query is obviously hard coded to search for BENNETT, if you need to select by other surnames hopefully you can work out what needs changing?